# Cannot access cookie in javascript

Tags: javascript

I created a function to get the cookie in javascript :

```
   function getCookie() {
        var arr = document.cookie.split(";");
        for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i].substr(0, arr[i].indexOf("=")).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") == "taxibleC") {
                return arr[i].substr(arr[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    var multipleVAT = 1;
```

And then I have another function to initialize the cookie :

```
  function ChangeVATValue() 
   {
      if ($("#vatEnable").is(':checked')) {
         multipleVAT = 1;
      } else {
         multipleVAT = 0;
      }
      document.cookie = "taxibleC=" + multipleVAT;
      alert(getCookie());
   }
```

When I used `alert(getCookie());`, It has the value 1.
But when I click to another page, the alert is 0.

Could anyone tell me, why I cannot access the session by using the `getCookie()` method in the view of my asp.net MVC 3.0 project.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you cookie might get expire immediatly, if possible se cookie expiration time to certail limit and than access the value of cookie on another page that resolve your issue

something like

```
document.cookie =
  'ppkcookie1=testcookie; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'
```

Comment: Do I have to put the `expires` ?

Comment: @socheata - i think its better to put expire if you problem not get resolve without expires...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `path` in the cookie for accessing in different page

`;path=/`

For example,

`document.cookie = 'YOUR COOKIE DATA;path=/'`

Comment: I added `;path=/` to `document.cookie` and change from `return arr[i].substr(arr[i].indexOf("=") + 1);` to `return arr[i].substr((arr[i].indexOf("=") + 1),1);`, but it still didn't work.